# CMake: Is there a way to get a list of imported targets that belong to a package

Tags: cmake, package

Sometimes I wish I could get a list of the imported targets that belong to a package. Is there a variable that holds them?

This would allow me to write something like this

```
find_package(Qt5 CONFIG REQUIRED)
message("Imported Qt5 targets: ${Qt5_IMPORTED_TARGETS}") # speculative code
```

With my current knowledge I have to rely on the documentation of the package to give me the names of all imported targets. Reading them from a variable or property would be easier.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but it would be extremely useful actually. Good question.

Comment: Great idea! I do not believe there is any direct way to do this at the moment. It is likely possible to hack something by scanning FindModule files (module mode) and targets.cmake files (config mode) for `add_executable(...IMPORTED)` and `add_library(...IMPORTED)` though.

Comment: You could, however, hack it by intercept calls to `add_library` by overwriting it, saving calls with `INTERFACE` and pass it on to the actual built-in function. E.g. as roughly described [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/cmake-developers@cmake.org/msg06929.html).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

CMake 3.21 introduced the directory property `IMPORTED_TARGETS` that can be used to get a list of all imported targets. This can be used to derive a list of targets that were imported by a single `find_package()` call when it is queried before and after the call to `find_package()`. The code could look something like this:

```
...
get_property(importTargets DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" PROPERTY IMPORTED_TARGETS)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)

get_property(importTargetsAfter DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" PROPERTY IMPORTED_TARGETS)
list(REMOVE_ITEM importTargetsAfter ${importTargets})

message("${importTargetsAfter}")
...
```

Usually it is good enough to only print the list of all imported targets and guess from the names which of them were imported by the package of interest.

Comment: Perfect, months of strange behavior solved in 2 minutes thanks to this answer. Kudos!

Answer (score 4):

Not precisely what you asked for, but for `Qt5`, one can do:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(so)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)

get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
foreach(_variableName ${_variableNames})
  if(_variableName MATCHES "^Qt5.*LIBRARIES")
      message(STATUS "${_variableName}")
      message(STATUS "\t${${_variableName}}")
  endif()
endforeach()
```

Example output:

```sh
-- Qt5Core_LIBRARIES
--  Qt5::Core
-- Qt5Gui_EGL_LIBRARIES
--  Qt5::Gui_EGL
-- Qt5Gui_LIBRARIES
--  Qt5::Gui
-- Qt5Gui_OPENGL_LIBRARIES
--  Qt5::Gui_GL
-- Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES
--  Qt5::Widgets
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/build
```

Caveat with approach: One needs to know the component names.